# How can I filter my array results when the user types in a search bar similarly to how it'd be done using a Model's DB table?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

Whenever I write `dd($searchedItem);` inside the filter function it displays:

Note: (I know filter won't display the entire list but we'll assume there are 50 array indexes):

```
array:3 [
   "InventoryID" => 1
   "Name" => "Instant $5 Amazon Gift Card"
   "Number" => "40, 171"
]
```

Here's my PHP:

```php
$inventoryList = $this->_inventoryRepository->getInventoriesWithNumbers();

$search = $request->get('search');

$searchedItems = collect($inventoryList);

if($search) {
    $searchedItems->filter(function ($searchedItem) {
        // dd($searchedItem); 
        $searchedItem->where('Name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
    });
}
```

I'm trying to test via Postman if I can `dd();` only the array index the user has searched in the search box.  So if the user types Amazon in the search box (in my case, `$search = $request->get('search');` since I'm testing with Postman), it should dump the Amazon array results only.

I'm basically trying to search by `Name`.  What's a good way to go about doing this?  I know how to do it via a db table but I this time, I gotta do it via an array.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to filter $searchedItems by Name?, just assign the filter result to an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

#### Case: $search is a single word

Eg: $search = 'Amazon' will search for records/elements where `Name` contains the word "Amazon"

```php
$searchedItems->filter(fn($item) => Str::contains($item['Name'], $search));
```

To make the search case insensitive i.e allow amazon or Amazon as search term

```php
$searchedItems->filter(
    fn($item) => Str::contains(strtolower($item['Name']), strtolower($search))
);
```

#### Case: $search is multiple words and match any word

Eg: $search = 'Amazon,Gift' and search for records/elements where `Name` contains either "Amazon" **OR** "Gift" - both words case insensitive

- the case of the search terms doesn't really matter as we convert to lowercase when comparing
- If case of search term is important then remove the `strtolower` when comparing

```php
$searchedItems->filter(
    fn($item) => Str::contains(
        strtolower($item['Name']), 
        explode(',', strtolower($search))
    )
);
 
//replace delimiter (,) with whatever you are using in explode
//or if you want to allow space and/or , use preg_split instead of explode
//preg_split("/[\s,]+/", strtolower($search))
```

#### Case: $search is multiple words and match all words

Eg: $search = 'Amazon,Gift' and search for records/elements where `Name` contains - "Amazon" **AND** "Gift" - both words case insensitive

- the case of the search terms doesn't really matter as we convert to lowercase when comparing
- If case of search term is important then remove the `strtolower` when comparing

```php
$searchedItems->filter(
    fn($item) => Str::containsAll(
        strtolower($item['Name']), 
        explode(',', strtolower($search))
    )
);
 
//replace delimiter (,) with whatever you are using in explode
//or if you want to allow space and/or , use preg_split instead of explode
//preg_split("/[\s,]+/", strtolower($search))
```

Comment: Couldn't fit in a comment so have updated the answer to provide more context

Comment: thanks a lot man, I truly appreciate you!

Comment: @someone Glad I could help. Pls remember to mark as accepted/upvote any of the provided answer(s) which helped you solve the issue in your question, for the benefit of subsequent visitors

Answer (score 2):

[`Str::contains`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-contains)

[`Str::containsAll`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-contains-all)

```
$searchedItems->filter(function ($searchedItem) use ($search) {
    // dd($searchedItem); 
    return Str::contains($searchedItem['Name'], [$search]);
});
```

PHP ^7.4

```php
$searchedItems->filter(fn ($searchedItem) => Str::contains($searchedItem['Name'], [$search]) );
```

- `Str::contains($searchedItem['Name']), [$search])` to search for an exact match.
- `Str::contains($searchedItem['Name']), explode(' ', $search))` if you want to search for any of the words in the search string.
- `Str::containsAll($searchedItem['Name']), explode(' ', $search))` if you want to search for all of the words in the search string.

Comment: Thanks man, I greatly appreciate it.  But I'm getting an error on the second parameter that says `Undefined variable $search` which doesn't make sense because it's clearly defined :(.

Comment: @someone That's because if you want to use a variable within a closure you have to inject it with `function($searchedItem) use($search) { ... }` then it will be available within the closure

Comment: @Donkarnash interesting, I never knew that, thanks so much for the knowledge! :D

Comment: @someone If you are on PHP 7.4 or later you can take advantage of arrow functions since there's just one statement within the closure like `$searchedItems->filter(fn($searchedItem) => Str::contains($searchedItem['Name'], [$search]));`. With arrow functions there's no need to inject external variable in the closure

Comment: @Donkarnash gotchaaaaa, thanks again!  I have another question:  It seems like this answer only works with the first item in the array (the same one I put in my original post in the beginning).  How would I make it so that it works with the rest of the list?  In other words, when I type "a", it returns true, but about for other entries?

Comment: @someone That's there in the answer if say you want to search for records which have either "Amazon" or "Walmart" then use `Str::contains($searchedItem['Name'], ['Amazon', Walmart'])` - search for Amazon **or** Walmart. If you want to search for records where the name contains "Gift" & "Amazon" use `Str::containsAll($searchedItem['Name'], ['Gift', 'Amazon'])` - search for Gift **and** Amazon